# RegEx to match certain floating numbers

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a Regular Expression, which should match the following cases:

Valid:

```
150.65
105.84
130.23
148210000.01
1000000
5023213.01
7401.5
```

Invalid:

```
0500
02
000000555
00
```

My current regex is

```
/^0?[1-9]*([.][0-9]{1,2})*$/
```

but it is not working as expected.

Comment: You probably need: `^[1-9][0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$`

Comment: @anubhava Actually I expect that `0.123` is a valid floating point number.  The restriction on not starting with zero only makes sense for pure integers.

Comment: My suggestion is as per the OP's requirement to match *certain floating numbers*

Comment: Still there are unclear cases. Would be easier if you phrase the requirements  in words too. If eg `01.1` should be invalid but eg `0.1` and `0` should be valid, try [`^(?:0\b|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d{1,2})?$`](https://regex101.com/r/U5MrBa/1)

Answer (score 2):

You may use the following pattern:

```
^(?:[1-9][0-9]*|[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+))$
```

This pattern insists that any integer must not start with zero.

```
^
    (?:[1-9][0-9]*  match any integer value starting in 1-9
    |               OR
    [0-9]+          match any decimal starting in 0-9 followed by
    (?:\.[0-9]+)    a decimal component
    )
$
```

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/TDE5dr/1).